# Por que o 'preview' dos layouts não aparece mais após atualizar para o Android Studio 3.0?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, atualização

Fiz a **atualização** do **Android Studio 2.3.3 para o 3.0**. A partir daí, só dor de cabeça: *projetos prontos com problema*.

Tanto na aba de design dos *layouts* como na janela de pré-visualização (*preview*), não aparece o desenho da tela (o *design* do *layout*). O que aparece na janela de pré-visualização é a mensagem `android..ActionBarOverlayLayout` conforme observado na imagem abaixo. Além disso, as consultas no banco de dados através de HTTP também pararam!

[image: imagem do problema]

**O que pode ser?**

Eu acredito q o problema tenha a ver com configuração e não código. Segue imagem da toolbar criada, que no android studio 2.3  aparecia no preview e na aba design, e nessa nova versão não está aparecendo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem como providenciar uma imagem maior ou ao menos incluir parte do código do problema na pergunta?

Comment: editei o post e acrescentei nova imagem. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Olha comigo anda acontecendo isso a maneira que encontrei de contornar está situação foi clicando no AppTheme e selecionando a seguinte opção:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: Material.Light.NoActionBar]

**Após selecionar está opção vá em Build e em seguida em Clean Project, já deve aparecer a visualização!**

Answer (score 0):

Aconteceu do mesmo jeito que com você, foi eu atualizar e deu esse problema.

Comigo eu simplesmente troco a versão do Android no preview e ele funciona, eu coloco 24 ou inferior.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]